# DNSCrypt error: could not load library "libsodium.so", on Asus Zenfone 2 running Android 5.0

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, command-line, asus-zenfone-2

I tried installing DNSCrypt on my Asus Zenfone 2 device. But when I try to run it it gives me this:

```
root@Z008_1:/ # dnscrypt enable
Enabling dnscrypt...
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
killall: dnscrypt-proxy: no process killed
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: could not load library "libsodium.so" needed by "/system/xbin/dnscrypt-proxy"; caused by library "libsodium.so" not found
Done
```

Did i forget something? I already put all the files in the correct directory, including the `libsodium.so`.

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled DNSCrypt for x86 sucessfully, [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!65oEBajT!abzsYAD1NSly4lspghju5yYppxGEkpz0vtatiizL1Yw) to download binary file for Zenfone 2.

Follow the instruction.

about libsodium.so, you should copy it to folder system/lib/